# Redirect POST request using tomcat valve

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat-valve

I need to redirect 
`https://ipaddress/index.jsp to https://ipaddress/v1/index.jsp`

Tomcat Version : 7.0.32

I have a valve configured in server.xml
`<Valve className="com.mycompnay.tomcatvalve.RedirectValve" portal="v1" />`

Here I have a class that extends ValveBase and I do response.sendRedirect after matching some patterns.
This works for GET request. But how do I redirect POST requests.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try giving in this format it shld work `response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectUrl("/v1/index.jsp"))`

I assume you have used a Servlet and your redirecting through that